# Is there a litecoin / dogecoin scrypt brain wallet generator like the one made for BTC warp wallet?

Tags: litecoin, dogecoin, address-generation, brain-wallet

Has there been other litecoin / dogecoin brain wallet implementations besides bitaddress? I don't feel bitaddress.org's brain wallet generator is secure enough as compared to Warp Wallet scrypt generation to prevent brute force attempts. Basically, looking for a warp wallet version for litecoin and dogecoin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a warpwallet implementation for Litecoin, it's available as a webpage you can use offline and as a go program.

You can use it [here](https://dvdbng.github.io/memwallet/). Link to github with the source code is also there.

Comment: Very nice work! How long did it take to do something like that? I've always wanted to rewrite the warp wallet code for other coins, but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: @Patoshi it took me a few hours to implement each of the other currencies in go (I did it because I wanted to use other currencies), and tree days or so to do the javascript version (did it for learning and because it's easier for other people to use it)

Comment: I would love to learn how you did it. Maybe write up a blog post about it? :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may not have to.  If you use the Wallet Details section on the Bitaddress site, you can plug in the WIF private key that Warpwallet gives you and get the 256-bit hex representation, which you can then use to construct a private key for any cryptocurrency that uses 256-bit keys.